# Safe Cursive Webfont?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to display the lower case letter "l" and not have it look like a "1".  Is there a "safe" (i.e. common) font style for this that I could reasonably expect to show up on everyone's computer?

I want to end up with something like: `<span style="font-family: SAFEFONT;">l</span>`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you opposed to loading a google font?

Comment: You can check http://cssfontstack.com/ to see if there is anything that meets your requirements.

Comment: I don't know anything about "Google Fonts".

Comment: @jeroen: Are these widely common fonts though?

Answer (score 0):

Most font's have `I`, `i`, `l` and `1` with similar looks. The same problem occurs with `0`, `o` and `O`. Sometimes these letters are omitted when there is no good context to deduce their meaning (passwords). But also when dealing with code, license plates distinguishable characters are important. My best guess is look at font's specifically designed for writing code. I think most of them don't have a true italic, but a  slanted roman and they are monospaced.

Text input on Stack Overflow does a decent job and has the following font stack:

```
font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
```